# How to disable arrow keys for dropdown/selector element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is a good jquery/javascript approach to prevent a user from using the up and down arrow keys to select options in a dropdown box (i.e. to force the user to only use the mouse to select menu options)? Thanks!

Comment: This goes against a default user experience why would you want to do this ?

Comment: Blind users are REALLY going to hate you if you do this. And don't say "My site does this and that, blind users won't be coming here anyway!" because that only makes you look ignorant.

Comment: Alright, taking everyone's advice, I went for an alternative solution rather than disabling the arrow keys. Basically, it would have been a time-saving kludge for a problem with a selector whose values depend on another selector - the arrow keys had the potential to permit the user to submit nonsense combinations of values in a form. It was just intended for the a prototype page, but you're right that it's bad practice to do this.

Comment: One example use case is a WebGL game, where selectors may choose a different game mode or level. It is possible for a select element and the GL canvas to be in focus at the same time in some browsers, creating a confusing experience.

Answer (score 11):

## #1. don't do that, <sub><sup>it futzes with user experience</sup></sub>

But if you are:

```
$('select').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) { //up or down
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - been trying this approach, but it's not doing the trick, for whatever reason.

Comment: I can give a reason why to do this: I want the Excel-like cell navigation experience to move the caret in a table of inputs(input,select,textarea) with Ctrl+ArrowKey, but Ctrl+Up/Down always make the select to change its value if it is focused.

Comment: I like this kind of answers: _DON'T DO THAT BECAUSE IS BAD, but here is how to do it, if you want to do it anyway_ :)

Comment: And here is another reason to do it: my specific set of users are moving from a MS DOS _software_ (sic) to a web application, and they EXPLICITLY demanded for navigating with arrow keys... so, here I am :/

Comment: Yes, I think, the "don't do that" part of the answer isn't especially helpful. I am trying to achieve the same to replace excel, so that the users get the experience they expect. It may not be the correct thing top do, but it is still better than using excel as a data input tool.

Comment: This solution works just on Chrome. It doesn't work either on Firefox or IE.

Comment: Any one have  solution of this which will worj in Firefox and other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

**FOR LATEST FIREFOX & CHROME** ( IE anyone? ;-)

I've adapted some code to mimic disabling Up and Down arrow keys as required. I had to do similar with arrowUp / pageUp and arrowDown / pageDown keys for my app in order to allow custom keyboard navigation (I preserved arrowLeft / arrowRight key functionality for vertical menu navigation). Notice that I applied a setTimeout, this seems to be needed for Firefox (latest) :

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'select', function (e) {
var optsel = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
if ( (e.which == 38 || e.which === 40) ) {
setTimeout(function(){$('select option[value="' + optsel +'"]').prop("selected", true)}, 0);
}
});
```

The trick was to save as variable the last value selected of select menu, then recalling it with the setTimeout method as required by Firefox (at least).